# Sending structure through pipe without losing data

Tags: c, struct, process, pipe

I have this structure:

```
typedef struct {
    int pid;
    char arg[100];
    int nr;
} Str;
```

The code is something like this:

```
int main() {
    int c2p[2];
    pipe(c2p);
    int f = fork();

    if (f == 0) { // child
        Str s;
        s.pid = 1234;
        strcpy(s.arg, "abcdef");
        s.nr = 1;

        close(c2p[0]);
        write(c2p[1], &s, sizeof(Str*));
        close(c2p[1]);
        exit(0);
    }

    // parent
    wait(0);
    close(c2p[1]);
    Str s;
    read(c2p[0], &s, sizeof(Str*));
    printf("pid: %d nr: %d arg: %s", s.pid, s.nr, s.arg);
    close(c2p[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is something like this:

```
pid: 1234 nr: 0 arg: abc$%^&
```

pid is always right, nr is always 0 and the fist few characters from arg are right followed by some random characters.

I want to create a structure in the child process and then send the structure to the parent process through pipe.

How can I send correctly this structure through pipe?

Comment: This `sizeof(Str*)` looks bad.

Comment: Your code misses the relevant `#include`s.

Answer (score 3):

```
write(c2p[1], &s, sizeof(Str*));
```

is not right. That would write only the number of bytes the size of a pointer. It should be

```
write(c2p[1], &s, sizeof(Str)); // -- without the `*`.
```

Similarly, you need to use:

```
read(c2p[0], &s, sizeof(Str));  // -- without the `*`.
```

Comment: Why not just `sizeof s`? This is less error-prine, in case the type of `s` changes.

Comment: I don't think the OP has posted real code, as `sizeof(Str *)` should not even compile.

Comment: @PaulR, `sizeof(Str *)` is a valid expression. It evaluates to the size of a pointer.

Comment: @RSahu: really ? `Str` is a struct - why would `Str *` be a pointer ?

Comment: @PaulR: You seem to be overlooking the leading `typedef`.

Comment: @PaulR: Have a break ... ;-)

Comment: @PaulR, `Str *` is a type, That's why you can use `sizeof(Str *)`.

Comment: @RSahu: thanks - I see it now - evidently I was suffering from Coders' Block temporarily. ;-)