# Risk of losing data when sending variables through pipe?

Tags: c, process, pipe

I have the following code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h> // may not be needed
#include <sys/stat.h> // may not be needed
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int pid;
    char arg[100];
    int nr;
} Str;

int main() {
    int c2p[2];
    pipe(c2p);
    int f = fork();

    if (f == 0) {
        Str s;
        s.pid = 1234;
        strcpy(s.arg, "abcdef");
        s.nr = 1;

        close(c2p[0]);
        write(c2p[1], &s, sizeof(Str));
        close(c2p[1]);
        exit(0);
    }

    wait(0);
    close(c2p[1]);
    Str s;
    read(c2p[0], &s, sizeof(Str));
    printf("pid: %d nr: %d arg: %s", s.pid, s.nr, s.arg);
    close(c2p[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

I have to say that it worked just fine until now (pid, nr and arg were never altered), but:

When the child process is done, is the memory segment (used by the child) destroyed (marked as free)?
If so, is there the risk that between the time of writing and the time of reading to lose the acces to that segment or the data to be altered?

(The original question was this: [Sending structure through pipe without losing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802517/sending-structure-through-pipe-without-losing-data/29803129#29803129) )

Comment: Checking the results of the library calls you're making is probably worthwhile, as is acting on those results accordingly. When the child process is done, naturally its memory is gone as well. But don't assume so is the data written on the pipe. That pipe still has an outstanding read-handle (and write handle, for that matter), since you didn't close the parent process write-side until after your `wait()`).

Answer (score 3):

Although the child process' memory is given back to the operating system when the process exits, I suspect this is not what you're really asking about.

You are more likely concerned about what happens to the data that was written to the pipe after the child process exits. As the pipe(2) man page states:

> Data written to the write end of the pipe is buffered by the kernel
>   until it is read from the read end of the pipe.

So your data will arrive, even if the process that wrote it has already exited.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was asking about.